# Box Plots in tikzpicture - Two Plots per y tick

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, boxplot

I need a Box plot with two boxes on each ytick. Any ideas?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        title=Scenario 1,
        height=6.0cm, width=8.0cm,
        xmin=6, xmax=20, xtick={6,8,...,20},
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={Mon, Tue, Wed},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
    ]
    \addplot [
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=15,
      lower quartile=8,
      upper whisker=19,
      lower whisker=7
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot [
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=17,
      lower quartile=10,
      upper whisker=19,
      lower whisker=7
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, though some manual fiddling is required. Start by reducing the height of the boxes, by adding `/pgfplots/boxplot/box extend=0.3` to the `axis` options. The default value is 0.8, adjust this to your liking.

Then for each plot, set `draw position` to some value slightly above or below the tick value. E.g. `draw position=1.2` and `0.8` as in this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        title=Scenario 1,
        height=6.0cm, width=8.0cm,
        xmin=6, xmax=20, xtick={6,8,...,20},
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={Mon, Tue, Wed},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    /pgfplots/boxplot/box extend=0.3
    ]
    \addplot+ [
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=15,
      lower quartile=8,
      upper whisker=19,
      lower whisker=7,
      draw position=1.2
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+ [
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=17,
      lower quartile=10,
      upper whisker=19,
      lower whisker=7,
      draw position=0.8
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```